# Conversion of X,Y in Decimal Degree form

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I found a DBF file from some govt site, It has X value as 6265001.698875606 
and Y value as 2287922.0458578467 and so on.

I want to convert these values into Decimal Degree format so that I could create points and could plot in my ArcGIS software, can anyone suggest me how to convert these values to decimal degree format?

Few more examples are:-

```
      X          ,          Y
6189755.067873105,  2289006.0368001014 
6203424.773145199   2289971.025355682 
6257970.097453281   2297143.056615263 
6360789.086368695   2298715.5160687715 
6342105.368158773   2299252.8617788553 
6186809.299486443   2300760.374511853
```

Comment: You dont have to convert into decimal degrees. You can still plot them if you know the coordinate system.

Comment: How can I ? please elaborate it.

Comment: What you are looking for is a transformation or reprojection. Chances are those values are UTM coordinates for the local UTM zone. Do you know roughly which area those coordinates are covering? Than you can look for the right UTM zone (google 'UTM Zone Map' for an overview of all zones), look up the EPSG code for that zone (google 'EPSG UTM Zone 14N' for example), and project them with that EPSG code in ArcGIS (right-click the shapefile in the catalog windows and set projection). Finaly, you can use the 'Project' Tool in the Data Management Toolbox  to reproject them into degrees (EPSG: 4326).

Comment: Thank you for the valuable comments, I am currently working in QGIS and facing same problem, can anyone suggest me how to tackle this problem in QGIS ? I have .xls file which is containing these columns not in shapefile.

Comment: Bera, I just want to create point using these values. I guess if someone has better understanding so there will be a better way to open it directly without conversion into Decimal Degree format or so.

Comment: Ok you still need to know the coordinate system

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I will go through the coordinate system.

Answer (score 4):

You need to know the coordinate system of the coordinates in order to plot and also if you want to convert into lat/long. For example check at data source if there is any documentation. Then do this:

1 - Run tool [Make XY Event Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm):

> Creates a new point feature layer based on x- and y-coordinates
>   defined in a source table. If the source table contains z-coordinates
>   (elevation values), that field can also be specified in the creation
>   of the event layer. The layer created by this tool is temporary.

After this the coordinates will be visible as points in the map.

2 - To make the layer permanent run [Copy Features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm):

> Copies features from the input feature class or layer to a new feature
>   class.

3 - And if you want to convert into lat/long run [Project](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm):

> Projects spatial data from one coordinate system to another.

Answer (score 2):

But if you really have no idea whether the original data is in UTM or some other local coordinate reference system (CRS) you have to do some sleuthing.  Add some data with the correct CRS to a new MXD.  Next, make an XY Event layer as @BERA suggests from your mystery data.  If the mystery data draws in the correct location then the XY data uses the same CRS as the dataframe.  If the XY data are not in the correct location then change the dataframe CRS until the data draw in the correct location.  Use caution-some datums  may have small differences in the shift depending on your location.

Comment: @Everyone,Thank you so much for your suggestion. I am working on it and will update once I get something fruitful.

Comment: Go to a Google my map, drop a pin in your area of interest, figure out the lat-long for that, look up the relevant UTM. If you are in the US, pretty likely it's a state plane system.